# Can Object of interface stop the activity garbage collection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, interface, garbage-collection

Does using an object of interface in function call prevent the activity from being garbage collected.
example use case is: using this interface to get the status of big file upload.

and what's the best practice to achieve the same result

```
object FileUploadMethods { 

   interface FileUploadResponse {

   fun onSuccess(url: String)

   fun onFail(exception: Exception)

   fun onProgress(progress: Int)   

   }

   fun uploadFile(file: File, response: FileUploadResponse){
     // Some Code
   }
}
```

```
class A : AppCompatActivity(){

   override onCreate(){


       FileUploadMethods.uploadFile(file, object : FileUploadMethods.FileUploadResponse{

          override fun onSuccess(url: String) {
           }

           override fun onFail(exception: Exception) {
           }

           override fun onProgress(progress: Int) {
           }

       })
   }

}
```

Comment: As long as your `object : FileUploadMethods.FileUploadResponse` contains any reference to activity fields/views/methods etc. it will.

Comment: @Pawel ok i guessed so, so what's the best practice to achieve the same result

Comment: I'd use a foreground service instead of static object because it's not subject to garbage collection. Instead of callback interface create a `LiveData` field and update if with whatever progress/result there is. Finally bind to that service from activity and observe `LiveData` which prevents activity leaks because it's lifecycle aware.

Comment: @Pawel ok this is smart and helpful so how to handle that example use case, that i wanna the progress and the exception and the file url, do i use 3 LiveDatas or what